# make: flex: Command not found

Tags: xubuntu, make

I am very new to Linux. I am using Xubuntu 14.10 on vmware and I am trying to make an executable. I typed `make` in the terminal, but the process stopped because of the error:

```
flex -Pfct_pddl lex-fct_pddl.l
make: flex: Command not found
makefile:66: recipe for target 'lex.fct_pddl.c' failed
make: *** [lex.fct_pddl.c] Error 127
```

From what I understand I need to install flex. I tried to go with this:

```
sudo apt-get install flex
```

but I got this:

```
Package flex is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'flex' has no installation candidate
```

Any idea of what I should do? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, support for 14.10 has reached EOL (End of Life) on July 23, 2015. Considering [upgrading](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) to current supported releases, or do a fresh install.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the open file, delete its contents and put this:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>  Save File

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>  Close Nano

Continue running:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install flex
```

Comment: That solved it! Thanks a lot. Just to know, what did it do?

Comment: When an Ubuntu release reaches its “end of life”, to install applications, You must change the repositories to old-releases.