# Ubuntu Login scene stopped

Tags: keyboard

I'm a newbie in Ubuntu and I have a problem in log-in scene. It doesn't response...

I'm using ubuntu 20.04

what I did is,

1. [make: flex: Command not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859125/make-flex-command-not-found)
   I followed above link 'Answer'. I removed whole sentences in **/etc/apt/sources.list**
   and wrote

> `code`

```
    deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
    deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
    deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
    deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
    deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe multiverse
    deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe multiverse
    deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
    deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
    deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

like that Answer said.
and I did

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install flex
```

too.

and I did reboot, and I got log-in scene. It doesn't response....
keyboard is good because when i hit Num Lock button, the indicating light toggles.

Please.. help me..

Comment: That answer is "4 years, 7 months" old, (as the text says) and **utopic**  is Ubuntu 14.10 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history .......... Solution : Probably reinstall the OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)